# Simple Modulo Question $6x = 9 \pmod{11}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am trying to solve $6x = 9\pmod{11}$

The solution suggests notice that $2*6 = 12 = 1 \pmod {11}$

$$6x = 9 \pmod {11}\\12x = 18 \pmod {11}\\x = 7 \pmod{11}$$

I don't get the final step from $12x = 18\pmod{11}$ to the solution.

Comment: Short answer: subtract 11

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fact that $2\cdot 6 \equiv 12 \equiv 1 \pmod {11}$ tells you that $2$ is the multiplicative inverse of $6 \pmod{11}$, i.e., $\;2\cdot 6 = 12 \equiv 1 \pmod{11}$

$$2\cdot 6 x\equiv 2\cdot 9 \pmod{11} \implies 1\cdot x \equiv 18 \pmod{11}$$ $$\iff \underbrace{x\equiv 18 - 11 \pmod{11} \iff x\equiv 7 \pmod{11}}_{\large *}$$

$(*)$ In short, we see that $18 \equiv 7 \pmod{11},\quad \text{since} 11 \mid (18 - 7) \;\text{i.e.} \;\; 11\mid 11$

---

Further notes:

It's also true that while $x = 7$ is a solution, $7$ here represents the residue class modulo $11$, which we can denote by $[7]$. $$x = [7] = \{11n + 7\mid n \in \mathbb Z\}$$

There are 11 residue classes modulo $11$:

$\{[0], [1], [2], \cdots , [10]\}$.

For $[k]$ modulo $11$, $0 \leq k \leq 10$, the elements of the class include all integers satisfying: $[k] = \{11n + k\mid n \in \mathbb Z\}$.

Comment: It is the inverse because $12 - 1 = 11$        $11/11= 1$ with no remainder?

Comment: Yes, that's one way of putting it: $12 - 1 = 11$ So $12 - 1 \equiv \pmod{11} \iff 12 \equiv 1 \pmod{11}.$ The inverse is because $2\cdot 6 = 12 = 1\cdot 11 + 1:$ remainder $1$.

Comment: Does that make sense?

Comment: I believe so. I am just trying to truly convince myself and really understand it properly.

Comment: I understand. Take your time with things. You might want to search math.se for questions, using, say, "modular equations", or "systems of modular equations" for some more examples, to get comfortable with the process. Keep practicing, and it won't take long before you see things more immediately.

Comment: Thank you for the help. It is much clearer now in my mind.

Comment: @amWhy: Clear and clean as usual +1!

Answer (score 3):

You should note that $12\equiv1\pmod{11}$ and $18\equiv7\pmod{11}$. That is why the last step holds.

Answer (score 0):

$6x \equiv 9 \mod 11 \implies 11k+9=6x \implies 22k+18=12x$ call it ($i$)

$12x \equiv x \mod 11 \implies 11m+x=12x$ and call this ($ii$)

Equate $(i)$ and $(ii)$.

$22k+18 =11m+x \implies 11(2k-m+1)+7=x \implies 11j+7$

Answer (score 0):

$6x \equiv 9 \pmod{11} \Rightarrow 2x\equiv 3 \pmod{11}  (\because (3,11)=1) \Rightarrow 2x\equiv 14 \pmod{11} (\because 14\equiv 3 \pmod{11}) \Rightarrow x\equiv 7 \pmod{11}.$